# Gridstack in PL/SQL dynamic content oracle apex 19.2

Tags: javascript, gridstack, oracle-apex-19.1

I have a problem. I want to make dynamic content with gridstack.
I want to add and delete the gridstack items.
The problem is that i can't remove them. I get a error.

When clicking on the X to remove the item, i get a error :
Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on draggable prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'destroy'

My code in the PL?SQL Dynamic content is:
                begin
                  sys.htp.p('');

```
              for r in (select seq_id 
                              ,c001 tlt_id
                              ,c002 tlt_nr
                              ,c003 tlt_wcl_id
                              ,c004 tlt_row
                              ,c005 tlt_col
                              ,c006 tlt_width
                              ,c007 tlt_height
                        from apex_collections
                        where collection_name = 'LAYOUT'
                        order by c004, c005)
              loop
                sys.htp.p('<div class = "grid-stack-item"' ||
                          '"data-gs-x="' ||
                          r.tlt_row ||
                          '" data-gs-y="' ||
                          r.tlt_col ||
                          '" data-gs-width="' ||
                          r.tlt_width ||
                          '" data-gs-height="' ||
                          r.tlt_height ||
                          '" data-nr="' ||
                          r.tlt_nr ||
                          '" data-gs-id="' ||
                          r.seq_id ||
                          '"><span class="g-nr">' ||
                          r.tlt_nr ||
                          '</span><i class="fa fa-times g-rem" 
                           onClick="grid.removeWidget(this.parentNode.parentNode)"></i>
                          </div>') ;
              end loop;

              sys.htp.p('</div>');
            end;
```

In Function and Global Variable Declaration i have this code:

```
                var grid = GridStack.init();
                    var options = {
                        width: 100,
                        height: 100,
                        float: false,
                        animate: true,
                        disableResize: false,
                        disableDrag: true,
                        cellHeight: 'auto',
                        cellHeightUnit: 'px',
                        removable: '',
                        removeTimeout: 100,
                        verticalMargin: 20,
                        acceptWidgets: '.grid-stack-item',
                        resizable: { handles: 'e, se, s, sw, w' },
                        alwaysShowResizeHandle: /Android|webOS|iPhone|iPad|iPod|BlackBerry|IEMobile|Opera Mini/i.test(navigator.userAgent)
                    };
                var widgetWidth = 100;
                var maxCol = 4;
                var fontSize = widgetWidth/2;

                function initStack()
                {

                  grid.addWidget('<div><div class="grid-stack-item-content">Item 1</div></div>', {width: 2});
                  grid.addWidget('<div><div class="grid-stack-item-content"><button onClick="grid.removeWidget(this.parentNode.parentNode)">X</button><br></div></div>', 0, 0, Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()), Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()), true);

                delRebind();    
                    console.log('grid has ');

                }

                function addItem() {
                     grid.addWidget('<div><div class="grid-stack-item-content"><button onClick="grid.removeWidget(this.parentNode.parentNode)">X</button><br></div></div>', 0, 0, Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()), Math.floor(1 + 3 * Math.random()), true);
                     delRebind();
                }

                function delItem() {
                   var liItem = $(this).parents("div");
                   var liItemNr = $(this).parents("div").attr("data-nr");   
                    el=$('.grid-stack-instance-7377').closest('.grid-stack-item');
                    grid.removeWidget(this.parentNode.parentNode);
                }

                function delRebind() {
                   $(".g-rem").off("click");
                   $(".g-rem").on("click", delItem);
                   $("div.grid-stack-item .g-nr").css("font-size",fontSize + "px").css("margin-top", (fontSize/2) + "px");

                }
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

I think it is related to a bug/issue of gridstack.

You can review the following issue: https://github.com/gridstack/gridstack.js/issues/1250